# Access to HttpStatusCode in C++ like Javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, arduino, arduino-esp8266

I am writing an Arduino project on ESP.

In Javascript (client side) I have this:

```
HttpStatusCode = { // Top10
  OK: 200,
  Created: 201,
  NoContent: 204,
  NotModified: 304,
  BadRequest: 400,
  Unauthorized: 401,
  Forbidden: 403,
  NotFound: 404,
  Conflict: 409,
  InternalServerError: 500
};
```

and in my code

```
   if( this.status == HttpStatusCode.OK ) {
     ...
   }
```

Now, in C++ (server side), how do you do the same thing?

```
   if( status == HttpStatusCode.OK ) {
     ...
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 and later, you can use a [scoped `enum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations), eg:

```cpp
enum class HttpStatusCode { // Top10
    OK = 200,
    Created = 201,
    NoContent = 204,
    NotModified = 304,
    BadRequest = 400,
    Unauthorized = 401,
    Forbidden = 403,
    NotFound = 404,
    Conflict = 409,
    InternalServerError = 500
};
```

Otherwise, use a `class` or `struct` with `static` constants in it, eg:

```cpp
struct HttpStatusCode {
    static const int OK = 200;
    static const int Created = 201;
    static const int NoContent = 204;
    static const int NotModified = 304;
    static const int BadRequest = 400;
    static const int Unauthorized = 401;
    static const int Forbidden = 403;
    static const int NotFound = 404;
    static const int Conflict = 409;
    static const int InternalServerError = 500;
};
```

Either way, you can then use them like this:

```cpp
if( status == HttpStatusCode::OK )
```